# Power Apps - Use LookUp fields in Search function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I wanted to use the Lookup field in a `Search` function for my *Gallery > Items* in Canvas App.

Currently I am using below query:

```
Search(
   'SRG Scan Quantitiess',
   TextBox_SearchInventory.Text,
   "productcategory",
   "productname",
   "sku",
   "manufacturer",
   "location_textfield"
)
```

But now, we have replaced the `location_textfield` with `location_lookupfield`.

**Is there any approach I can use this?**

**P.S. -** I have referred [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup#syntax) for syntax of "Search" function but does not seem much helpful for this scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: using AddColumns() create a virtual column where the lookup is reduced to text. Then use the virtual column to perform the search.

```
Search(AddColumns('SRG Scan Quantitiess',"LocationText",location_textfield.Value),TextBox_SearchInventory.Text,"productcategory","productname","sku","manufacturer","LocationText")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the same approach, I tried for [using LookUp fields in GroupBy] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816855/power-apps-use-lookup-fields-in-groupby-function) - but throwing an error.

Comment: provided an answer for your other question as well

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to search on lookup columns is to create a formula column in the source table referring to the lookup column / lookup field, which flattens it into a text value that can be searched. This also works with choices