# Use LookUp fields in GroupBy function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I want to use the `LookUp fields` - **Location** & **Bin** - but facing error in that.

Here's the working code that in my canvas app.

```
Filter(
    AddColumns(
        GroupBy(
            BinData,
            "bincode",      //old text field
            "location",     //old text field
            "productname",
            "uom",
            "GroupBins"
        ),
        "TQ",
        Sum("eachcount")
    ),
    Not(IsBlank(bincode))
)
```

To which I want to use new lookup fields and tried below code but it is throwing an error:

```
Filter(
    AddColumns(
        GroupBy(
            AddColumns(BinData,"LocationText",Location.'Location Name'),
            AddColumns(BinData,"BinText",Bin.'Bin Name'),
            "BinText",
            "LocationText",
            "productname",
            "uom",
            "GroupBins"
        ),
        "TQ",
        Sum("cr5fa_culebraeachcount")
    ),
    Not(IsBlank(BinText))
)
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share the error message, but if I guess correctly, the issue is with your second argument in the GroupBy() function.
[GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-groupby) expects a data source, and then column names as text. Instead you put another AddColumns for the second argument, which returns a table, creating a data type mismatch.

You need to merge your AddColumns functions (e.g. convert both lookup columns in one step):

```
Filter(
AddColumns(
    GroupBy(
        AddColumns(BinData,"LocationText",Location.'Location Name',"BinText",Bin.'Bin Name'),
        "BinText",
        "LocationText",
        "productname",
        "uom",
        "GroupBins"
    ),
    "TQ",
    Sum("cr5fa_culebraeachcount")
),
Not(IsBlank(BinText))
```

)

Sometimes the virtual columns we add using AddColumns need to reference each other. In such cases, you can nest AddColumns().